# how can i accept quickfix acceptor sessions over 2 IPs and ports?

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

This is for internal and external DNS settings. So my config file says:

```
connectionType=acceptor
SenderCompID=provider
TargetCompID=client1
SocketAcceptAddress=X.X.X.X
SocketAcceptPort=1901
```

and then

```
connectionType=acceptor
SenderCompID=provider
TargetCompID=client2
SocketAcceptAddress=url.mapping.to.X.X.X.X
SocketAcceptPort=1902
```

and the acceptor won't run with error:

```
quickfix.RuntimeError: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to use the internal socket address for all clients, but then get LAN clients to use the internal DNS "machine1" and external clients to use the external DNS "remote.machine1.com"

So the config looks like this:

```
connectionType=acceptor
SenderCompID=provider
TargetCompID=client1
SocketAcceptAddress=192.168.20.25
SocketAcceptPort=1901

connectionType=acceptor
SenderCompID=provider
TargetCompID=client2
SocketAcceptAddress=192.168.20.25
SocketAcceptPort=1901
```

Each client is on the same port...

Answer (score 1):

> SenderCompID=provider,
>    TargetCompID=client1

Both of are the same. If I remember correctly Quicfix identifies an unique session by BeginString, SenderCompID, TargetCompID. So if these are the same for 2 sessions you will get an error. So either one of them has to be different from the other.

Secondary query is why would you be doing this ? Is this for failover ?

Comment: thanks.. hmm... I don't think this was the problem. I am doing this because the acceptor takes sessions external to the LAN and internal on the LAN. For DNS reasons the internal sessions can't map to the external IP address...

Comment: And it was my bad, a typo the clients are different !!